# R install package Rcplex

Tags: r, installation, cplex

I already follow INSTALL STEP at [INSTALL](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcplex/INSTALL)
but something wrong happen when I install the package

```
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I"C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1263/cplex/include" -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include" -O3 -Wall -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c Rcplex.c -o Rcplex.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I"C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1263/cplex/include" -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include" -O3 -Wall -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c Rcplex_QCP.c -o Rcplex_QCP.o
Rcplex_QCP.c: In function 'Rcplex_QCP':
Rcplex_QCP.c:37:7: warning: unused variable 'trace' [-Wunused-variable]
int trace = INTEGER(getListElement(control,"trace"))[0];
    ^
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I"C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1263/cplex/include" -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include" -O3 -Wall -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c Rcplex_params.c -o Rcplex_params.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I"C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1263/cplex/include" -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include" -O3 -Wall -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c Rcplex_utils.c -o Rcplex_utils.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcplex1263
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Rcplex'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you go to the package documentation at: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcplex/index.html ... You make no mention of satisfying the system requirements:

```
SystemRequirements: IBM ILOG CPLEX libraries and headers
```

Comment: I have the software CPLEX. but still can't install
so is that the package can not use for windows?

Comment: Can you run the CPLEX code without using R?  http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.studio.help/Optimization_Studio/topics/COS_relnotes_intro.html

Comment: I do not. Offhand it looks like a compiler mismatch with the version used to construct the package. You really are not providing sufficient information about all of the versions for programs you are using. You didn't even provide the script you used. It looks nothing like the material you reference in the INSTALL link.

Comment: I should provide CPLEX  and R version? or what should I provided?
what does that means "script"?

Comment: Yes all that and the versions of the C compiler and `make`. There was a multiple line version of a installation script in the page you referred to. [And] What system commands are you using to verify that CPLEX_DIR is set correctly.

Comment: my cplex and R version are 12.6.3 , 3.3.1 respectively. I am so sorry...
but how do I check my C compiler version...?
I am windows user. 
and I just follow the INSTALL page about the part of windows that modify the file content.

Answer (score 0):

The linker that `gcc` uses, `ld`, cannot find the shared library for CPLEX.  According to the INSTALL document, you need to verify that `CPLEX_LIB_PATH` is defined to point to the path where the CPLEX dll's are located.  From your output, I'd venture

```
set CPLEX_LIB_PATH="C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community1263/cplex/lib"
```

is what you need.